# "ls -lh" reports total size less than sum of individual sizes

Tags: files, ls, disk-usage

Under what circumstances would `ls -lh` show a total that is less than the sum of the individual files? For example:

```
$ ls -lh /var/lib/nova/instances/_base
total 100G
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova 4.3M 2012-02-14 14:07 00000001
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova 5.7M 2012-02-14 14:07 00000002
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova  42G 2012-03-08 15:24 1574bddb75c78a6fd2251d61e2993b5146201319.part
-rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   24M 2012-02-14 14:07 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb_sm
-rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   65G 2012-03-02 12:43 bd307a3ec329e10a2cff8fb87480823da114f8f4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm  160G 2012-02-24 16:06 ephemeral_0_160_None
-rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   80G 2012-02-24 22:38 ephemeral_0_80_None
-rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   10G 2012-02-24 22:37 fe5dbbcea5ce7e2988b8c69bcfdfde8904aabc1f
-rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   10G 2012-02-24 11:09 fe5dbbcea5ce7e2988b8c69bcfdfde8904aabc1f_sm
```

Edit: now showing some extra flags are per request in comment:

```
$ ls -aiFlh  /var/lib/nova/instances/_base/
total 143G
29884440 drwxrwxr-x 2 nova         nova 4.0K 2012-03-08 15:45 ./
29884427 drwxr-xr-x 6 nova         nova 4.0K 2012-03-08 15:05 ../
29884444 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova 4.3M 2012-02-14 14:07 00000001
29884445 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova 5.7M 2012-02-14 14:07 00000002
29884468 -rw-r--r-- 1 nova         nova  65G 2012-03-08 15:59 1574bddb75c78a6fd2251d61e2993b5146201319.converted
29884466 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nova         nova  58G 2012-03-08 15:35 1574bddb75c78a6fd2251d61e2993b5146201319.part
29884446 -rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   24M 2012-02-14 14:07 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb_sm
29884467 -rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   65G 2012-03-02 12:43 bd307a3ec329e10a2cff8fb87480823da114f8f4
29884443 -rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm  160G 2012-02-24 16:06 ephemeral_0_160_None
29884442 -rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   80G 2012-02-24 22:38 ephemeral_0_80_None
29884447 -rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   10G 2012-02-24 22:37 fe5dbbcea5ce7e2988b8c69bcfdfde8904aabc1f
29884441 -rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   10G 2012-02-24 11:09 fe5dbbcea5ce7e2988b8c69bcfdfde8904aabc1f_sm
```

Comment: don't know if any of those are links, could you list `ls -aiFl`
h

Comment: @bdowning Added the additional flags. Note there have been some changes to the directory, but the issues is still there

Comment: How about `du -h --total` for same dir?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It will happen if you have sparse files:

```
$ mkdir test; cd test
$ truncate -s 1000000000 file-with-zeroes
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 gim gim 1000000000 03-08 22:18 file-with-zeroes
```

A sparse file is a file which has not been populated with filesystem blocks (or only partially). When you read a non-populated zone of a sparse file you will obtain zeros. Such blank zones do not require actual disk space, and the 'total' reported by `ls` corresponds to the disk space occupied by the files (just like `du`).

Comment: Your kvm disk images are probably full of holes :-)

Comment: The [coreutils documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html) says that the `-s`/`--size` option "Print the disk allocation of each file to the left of the file name. This is the amount of disk space used by the file, which is usually a bit more than the file's size, **but it can be less if the file has holes**." The `-l` option of course prints the size, too.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the output given by `ls -l` and `du` has a subtle but very important difference. Try this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=aaa bs=1024 count=1
```

Now

```
ls -l aaa
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc 1024 2012-03-08 15:45 aaa
```

Whereas

```
du -h aaa
4.0K    aaa
```

This is because the filesystem allocates size in chunks of 4096 ( on my linux box). It is called IO Block. You can see this by:

```
    stat aaa
  File: `aaa'
  Size: 1024        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

Comment: Also, you can try `stat` on my proposed `empty-file`, and you'll see that the number of Blocks is 0, even if the file is reported to have a size of 1G.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Why does it report Blocks as 8 though? What block is this with size 512 bytes?

Comment: It's a bit strange, In the old times, IO blocks had size 512, but now they are usually 4K. `stat` reports the equivalent number of old sized block needed to store all the 4K blocks (that is 8 times the real number of 4K blocks).

Answer (score 3):

[The currently accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33803/9041) is absolutely correct, just if you want to see apparent size, you can use:

`du --apparent-size`

> print  apparent  sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like