# Why does the "du" command count in 4KB steps?

Tags: disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Directory size calculation difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/directory-size-calculation-difference)

I don't understand how the `du` command under Linux works.
I wanted to count the overall size of a few hundred, small files and `du -sh` returned something along the lines of 150MB. I didn't question it until I realized my file manager displayed only around 50MB for the same set of data and I got confused.

Here's what I then tried:

```
fkochem@WK-6:~/temp$ cat test 
a
fkochem@WK-6:~/temp$ du -sh test 
4.0K    test
```

So, now this must be a mistake? I looked at `du -sh *` of my original data and found the following:

```
4.0K    NCO-0.9.9.9.json
4.0K    NCO-0.99.9.json
4.0K    NCO-0.9.9.json
8.0K    NCO-0.99.json
8.0K    NCO-0.9.json
```

Why does `du` seem to count in 4KB steps? What am I missing here?

Comment: 4k is the size of a single disk block.  Disk space is allocated in blocks, so even the smallest disk takes up one block (4k) on your disk.

Comment: For completeness, to get the exact size of a small file I'd suggest `wc -c`. If you need the sum, you can always `cat *.json | wc -c`, or for a recursive version `find . -name "*.json" -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

du is disk usage, and it counts that amount of disk allocated to the file. The minimum "block size" (i.e. the minimum chunk allocated to a file) is usually 4k.  So the file-system counts in 4k chunks, not du.

It would count in 1k chunks if you formatted a drive as follows:

```
mke2fs -b 1024 /dev/XXX
```