# Why two folders with the same contents have different sizes?

Tags: rsync, backup, file-copy, corruption

I just created a copy of my music library, let's call it `music_backup`, and also have the original folder, called `music`. The backup folder was created using the trusted `rsync`, so no weird tools involved here or anything. However I noticed something strange: when I do `du --total music_backup` and `du --total music` I get different results (22269244 to 22269272, respectively).

So here's my question: considering these two folders are an identical copy of one another, should their sizes not be the same? Or this small difference means there was some file corruption in the copying process?

Comment: Don't miss [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19896/108618) where it reads "the directory size varies depending on historic circumstances".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, that was helpful!